# does VARCHAR increase the capacity of the variable assigned to it?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
City CHAR(10),
Street VARCHAR(10)
```

One thing i understood is varchar is having variable length . but what in the above case - if the name of the street is more than 10 characters - then does it increase he size again by 10 units by default ? . Please clarify it .

Comment: Also note that the capacity may be in bytes, not characters (i.e. you may not be able to fit 10 emoji in).

Answer (score 2):

No, you will get an error if you try to insert a larger string.

[Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i45694):

> **VARCHAR2 Data Type**
>   The VARCHAR2 data type specifies a variable-length character string. When you create a VARCHAR2 column, you supply the maximum number of bytes or characters of data that it can hold. Oracle subsequently stores each value in the column exactly as you specify it, provided the value does not exceed the maximum length of the column. If you try to insert a value that exceeds the specified length, then Oracle returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not how it works. `CHAR` is a fixed with string: so if you put less that that length in, it is padded with, presumably, spaces; if you put more in, it <s>is truncated</s> throws an error. `VARCHAR` (and `VARCHAR2` in Oracle) allocates a maximum length, but no padding will be added to the string if you don't meet that length; however, again, <s>your input will be truncated</s> you'll get an error if it's too big (the field won't grow automatically).

For arbitrary text input, you'd use a `BLOB` or `CLOB` type. Either that, or store the text in the filesystem somewhere and point to its path in your DB.

Comment: "*your input will be truncated if it's too big*" - that's wrong. If you try to assign a value bigger then the maximum it will throw an error.

Comment: You're right: I stand corrected...been a while since I did any serious SQL! Edited

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to create a test case to see how it works:

```
create table test1 (col1 char(10),
                    col2 varchar(10));

-- create data with varying lengths
insert into test1 (col1, col2)
select lpad('a', level, 'a') col1,
       lpad('a', level, 'a') col2
from   dual
connect by level <= 10;

-- see the length of the stored values for each row
select col1, col2, length(col1), length(col2)
from   test1
order by col1, col2;

COL1       COL2       LENGTH(COL1) LENGTH(COL2)
---------- ---------- ------------ ------------
a          a                    10            1
aa         aa                   10            2
aaa        aaa                  10            3
aaaa       aaaa                 10            4
aaaaa      aaaaa                10            5
aaaaaa     aaaaaa               10            6
aaaaaaa    aaaaaaa              10            7
aaaaaaaa   aaaaaaaa             10            8
aaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaa            10            9
aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa           10           10

-- insert 11 characters into col1
insert into test1 (col1, col2)
values ('12345678901', null);

ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCHEMA"."TEST1"."COL1" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)

-- insert 11 characters into col2
insert into test1 (col1, col2)
values (null, '12345678901');

ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCHEMA"."TEST1"."COL2" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)

commit;

drop table test1;
```